# An insert caused a deadlock in InnoDB. How did this happen?

Tags: mysql, insert, innodb, deadlock

My question is this: Why does transaction 1 hold the primary lock and why does transaction 2 need primary lock? I can't find any information about this lock in mysql manual.

Information about this deadlock:

transaction 1:

```
1988266681 Query        BEGIN
1988266681 Query        INSERT IGNORE INTO `tab1`
                            (`sn`, `is_fetch`, `is_done`, `add_time`)
                            VALUES ('4287', 0, 0, 1403186277)
1988266681 Query        COMMIT
```

transaction 2:

```
1988212988 Query        BEGIN
1988212988 Query        SELECT sn FROM tab1 WHERE is_fetch = 0
                            LIMIT 200 FOR UPDATE
1988212988 Query        UPDATE `tab1` SET `is_fetch` = 1
                            WHERE sn in ('4287', '4387', '4487', '4587', '4687',
                            '4787', '4887', '4987')
1988212988 Query        COMMIT
```

schema info:

```
CREATE TABLE `tab1` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`sn` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`is_fetch` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
`is_done` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
`add_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `sn` (`sn`),
KEY `is_fetch` (`is_fetch`),
KEY `is_done` (`is_done`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4387619 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

deadlock info：

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
140617 23:25:36
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 36E4099DA, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 1937033606, OS thread handle 0x2ae3b0040700, query id 18031163883 192.168.1.65 db1 update
INSERT IGNORE INTO `tab1` (`sn`, `is_fetch`, `is_done`, `add_time`) VALUES ('1887', 0, 0, 1403018736)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 625 page no 5 n bits 1616 index `is_fetch` of table `db1`.`tab1` trx id 36E4099DA lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1476 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
1: len 4; hex 80410669; asc  A i;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 36E4099D7, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows, thread declared inside InnoDB 458
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
6 lock struct(s), heap size 3112, 51 row lock(s), undo log entries 7
MySQL thread id 1937007092, OS thread handle 0x2ae8b5a26700, query id 18031163880 192.168.1.130 db1 Updating
UPDATE `tab1` SET `is_fetch` = 1 WHERE sn in ('1187', '1287', '1387', '1487', '1587', '1687', '1787')
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 625 page no 5 n bits 1616 index `is_fetch` of table `db1`.`tab1` trx id 36E4099D7 lock_mode X locks gap before rec
Record lock, heap no 1476 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
1: len 4; hex 80410669; asc  A i;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 625 page no 3 n bits 440 index `PRIMARY` of table `db1`.`tab1` trx id 36E4099D7 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 168 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 80411598; asc  A  ;;
1: len 6; hex 00036e4099da; asc   n@  ;;
2: len 7; hex e80000c0060110; asc        ;;
3: len 14; hex 3134303631373338343331383837; asc 1887;;
4: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
6: len 4; hex d3a05df0; asc   ] ;;
```

Comment: What's the point of the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` before the `UPDATE`?

Comment: As to why transaction 2 needs the primary key lock, the `SELECT` is most likely not using the `is_fetch` index, but rather, it's scanning the rows (via the primary key).

Answer (score 3):

**Q:** How did this happen?

Transaction 2 obtained an exclusive lock on records in the 'is_fetch` index, and attempted to obtain a lock on records in the PRIMARY key of the table.

Transaction 1 obtained an exclusive lock on records in the PRIMARY key of the table, and attempted to obtain a lock on records in the `is_fetch` index.

InnoDB automatically detects that neither transaction can proceed, because each is holding resources needed by the other. InnoDB terminates one of the transactions so the other transaction can proceed.

Note that an INSERT statement can obtain a "gaps" lock for records in unique indexes. It's not just INSERT that caused the deadlock, it was the combination of transactions that were running concurrently.

InnoDB record locking is documented in the MySQL Reference manual here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html

Answer (score -1):

SELECT ... FOR UPDATE acquire lock for scanned rows. You can reed more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html and here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html